# Component Services - Transactions tab missing. How to show it?

Tags: windows, com, dcom, mmc

I'm trying to change the DCOM timeout for my COM component. [This page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms688387(v=vs.85).aspx) and virtually all other sources on the Internet speak of a Transactions tab in Component Services where I could change the timeout for my particular component. But on my Win10 x64 installation this tab is not displayed; below is a picture of what I'm seeing for all registered components.

Question: How do I get the Transactions tab to appear?

[image: Transactions tab missing]

Comment: Hmm, there is no such thing as a "DCOM timeout".  Transactions timeouts are a property of COM+, the component has to be configured to use transaction support first.  [Read this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: I'm looking for a concrete method of configuring my component to use transactions. All I can find is (1) stories about transactions and (2) sample code that works on already configured components. These pages for instance: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687663(v=vs.85).aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684367(v=vs.85).aspx. (Or maybe I'm missing something?)

Comment: The MSDN page [is here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685959%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  Whether that's what you actually want is still very hard to see.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably trying to configure an out-of-process / EXE-based COM server. These do not support enhanced COM+ services, such as transactions, since they always run as non-configured components. Only in-process / DLL-based servers can provide COM+ services. If you want to support transactions, you have two options:

- Switch to a DLL-based server
- Allow your EXE-Server to support transactions via a proxy component

Comment: It is in fact a remote COM server. My "root" problem is the long timeout when I lose Ethernet connectivity to the remote computer; COM calls will return after around one minute. I need these to return faster. The solution to this seems to me to be transaction-based COM calls, with transaction timeout configured by me to a few seconds. (I'll update my question with this information.)

Comment: Transactions are used in combination with databases. Are you sure that's what you're looking for? If you're rather interested in specifying a user defined timeout for your DCOM server, then it seems that this isn't possible. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2328551/what-determines-how-long-does-an-out-of-process-com-server-takes-to-notice-that) or [here](http://blog.matrikonopc.com/index.php/ask-the-experts-opc-questions-and-answers/8-what-is-the-minute-dcom-timeout/) for further details.